# Nginx and Angular 404 on assets

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx

I have a Angular 9 app which base href is "./". Nginx serve only in /route1/route2/
The app works fine with nginx, I can go to localhost:8080/route1/route2 and angular routes start working properly. The problem I found is that assets are not found. So right now, components are loaded correctly but without assets.

assets folder is under src/

Nginx config file:

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 4096; }

http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location /route1/route2 {
            try_files $uri /app/index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG mode
### STAGE 1: Build ###

FROM node:alpine AS build

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install && mkdir /app-ui && mv ./node_modules ./app-ui

WORKDIR /app-ui

COPY . .

RUN npm run ng build -- --deploy-url=/app/

### STAGE 2: Run ###

FROM nginx:alpine

# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by the proyect
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=build /app-ui/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

UPDATE!

I found that the images are in /localhost:8080/app/assets/...
The problem now is the server is trying to load the assets from ...8080/route1/route2/assets...

Comment: are you using relative paths when you reference /assets/? it should be absolute paths starting from root. i.e. <img src="/assets/test.jpg">

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be with the `angular.json` file. Make sure you include the `src/assets` in assets array of `angular.json`